# Can't map Integer

Tags: clojure

```
(Integer. "1") ; => 1
(map Integer. ["1" "2"])
; CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Integer., compiling:(/tmp/form-init6181502527198258116.clj:1:1)
```

What am I doing wrong here or is there some kind of gotcha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer.` is the same as `new Integer`. You want:

```
(map #(Integer. %) ["1" "2"])
```